# Pass data to web component (angular 6) inside LWC (Lightning Web Component)

Tags: lightning-web-components, angular, web-components

I have Angular 8 app defined as web component and
I have Lightning Web Component (LWC) app.

Inside LWC I am trying to pass data into web component through the property of DOM element like

```
this.template.querySelector('my-custom-element').myCustomProp = {isWork: false}
```

and it fails.
But on visual force page it works fine.

In debug console **myCustomProp** is available on element in case of using of it in visual force page but not in case with LWC.
Seems the reason of fail is **Locker Service**

Also passing of data as string through *setAttribute* works fine:

```
my-custom-element.setAttribute('my-custom-prop', '{isWork: true}');
```

Who was facing with that problem? Any solution?

Comment: Maybe try lwc:dom="manual" on the element?

Comment: already use, does not impact on it

Answer (score 2):

Also have faced this problem.
This solution:

```
my-custom-element.setAttribute('my-custom-prop', '{isWork: true}');
```

works for me. But have to add that *my-custom-prop* should be named starting with ***data***: *data-my-custom-prop* otherwise it will not work. The final working version will be:

```
my-custom-element.setAttribute('data-my-custom-prop', '{isWork: true}');
```